# Why statements after the while loop are not always executed?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am very new to python and I have encountered the following code:

```
def function(array):
    i = 0
    j = 10
    while i < j:
        if array[i]!=array[j]
            return False
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    return True
```

I can't understand why the `True` value is not always assigned to the function no matter what happens in a `while` loop. The `while` loop just seems to check the `if` statement, and after finishing the loop, the `True` value should be assigned to the function anyway. But this code works as follows: the `if` statement checks for the condition and if it is true, we assign `False` to the function, if it is not true, we assign `True` to the function. But the assignment of `True` is not inside the while loop, so we should have assigned the `True` to function anyway, no matter what happens in `while` loop. I can't understand the logic here, can anyone enlighten me in this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A `return` statement is not an assignment.

Comment: "why the `True` value is not always assigned to the function" - the `True` value is returned from the function, not assigned to it. And in any case, there is no such thing as assigning a value to a function. Assigning `x` to `y` means you set `y` to the value of `x`, i.e., you do `y = x`.

Comment: This is an extremely basic question. I _strongly_ recommend learning more about programming (this is a programming issue, not a Python issue) before attempting anything else.

Comment: Alexander Cecile, of course, I know it is a very basic question (as I already stated in my question itself) that I couldn't find an answer for. Isn't it reasonable to ask questions here that you couldn't figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A return statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result...

A return statement ends the function.
From https://www.python-course.eu/python3_functions.php

Answer (score 2):

A `return` is used to hand the control of the program back to the calling function. So when you're in the while loop, and your condition in the if clause is evaluated to be true, your `function` terminates execution and the control of the program is handed back to the calling function. The only scenario in which your function will return true would be if the conditions in your if clause was never satisfied during the execution of your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Return exits the current function or method.

when you return False in if statement it will not continue the rest of the code and will always return false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is likely to have gotten executed before the rest of the loop has a chance to finish. When

```
if array[i]!=array[j]
```

is met, return False is called, exiting the loop and returning False.

This happens because

```
array[i]!=array[j]
```

is the condition that is met first, before the loop can finish and return with True.

Instead, you may want to 'skip' the part of the loop where this condition is met. If so, use the keyword

```
continue
```

This 'skips' the current iteration to the next one, and will continue on with your loop.

Code as follows:

```
  while i < j:
    if array[i]!=array[j]:
      continue
```